# How to have two inline radio buttons in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to have two inline radio buttons in ASP.NET MVC but the label and its corresponding radio button are not aligned to each other.`
                                {terms and Condition goes here}

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="Terms" value="Yes" />Yes
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="Terms" value="No" />No
</label>
```

but my result [does not have the radio button and the label together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEqOT.png)

Comment: Which Bootstrap version you're using? Still no repro on my test project, probably you should check for CSS settings used in view.

Answer (score 1):

Put both in one div tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="Terms" value="Yes" />Yes
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="Terms" value="No" />No
</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```